# Find and replace tab in array with whitespace?

Tags: c, arrays

The purpose of this exercise is to create a program that can read the contents of a file and copy it to a new one. But there is also another thing to do that I do not know how to do:
I should also replace all tabs ('\t') that i find in files with 7 white space.
How can I solve this latter problem? Thank you.

I tried it with these lines of code, but obviously not working. It also also shows the following warning:

> warning C4047: '=': 'char' differs in levels of indirection from 'char [8]'

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    if (buf[i] == '\t') {
        buf[i] = "       ";
    }
}
```

This is my code: (of course if it can be improved in some way, do not hesitate to tell me. Thank you)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char buf[500];
    FILE *fp, *nuovo;
    errno_t err, err1;

    /*lettura e creazione file*/
    if (err = fopen_s(&fp, "text.txt", "r")) {
        printf("Errore");
    } else {
        printf("File Letto");
    } 
    if (err1 = fopen_s(&nuovo, "nuovo.txt", "w")) {
        printf("Errore");
    } else {
        printf("File Creato");
    }

    int x = fread_s(buf, sizeof(buf), 1, 500, fp);
    /*THIS IS THE PLACE FOR THE MISSING CODE*/


    fwrite(&buf, 1, x, nuovo);
    fclose(fp);
    fclose(nuovo);
}
```

Comment: `buf[i] = "       ";` (doesnt show the 7 spaces in inline code ...)  you are trying to add 7 characters into 1 char

Comment: I know it's wrong but I don't know how to do it

Comment: one possibility would be to read or write single characters, check if the character is a tab and replace it with 7 spaces if it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot replace one character with a string, which has many characters.

One approach to solving this problem is as follows: instead of making the replacement in place, you could do it while performing the output.

Loop through the characters in `buf`, and check if `buf[i]` is a `TAB`. If it is not a `TAB`, call `fputc(buf[i], nuovo)`. Otherwise, call `fputs("       ", nuovo)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a new dynamic allocate buffer wher you copy all characters from your source and substitute tab by spaces:

```
#include <malloc.h>


const char *whitespace = "       ";
int whitespaceLen = strlen( whitespace );
int newBufSize = 0;
char *newBuf = NULL;
int newBufPos = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
{
    int isTab = buf[i] == '\t';               // test if next char in buf is tab
    int charSize = isTab ? whitespaceLen : 1; // size which is neede for next char in newBuf

    if ( newBufPos + charSize < newBufSize ) // test if newBuf is large enough
    {
        newBufSize += 500;
        char *temp = realloc( newBuf, newBufSize ); // enlarge newBuf
        if ( temp == NULL )
        {
            free( newBuf ); // out of memory, free newBuf an terminate
            newBuf = NULL;
            break;
        }
        newBuf = temp;
    }

    if ( isTab )
    {
         memcpy( newBuf+newBufPos, whitespace, whitespaceLen ); // copy whitespace blanks to newBuf
         newBufPos += whitespaceLen ;
    }
    else
         newBuf[ newBufPos++ ] = buf[i];  // copy char to newBuf
}
```

Note somewhere you have to `free( newBuf );`